# Jquery jcart Maximum quantity of one for a specific item

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to limit a specific shop item so that it can only be added to the jcart once?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably more easily do this with simple logic than built-in functionality from the plugin.

The pseudo code would be as follows:

```
On the attempted addition of an item to the cart:
  if (item already exists in cart AND item hasProperty('onceOnly')):
    return false;
  else:
    add to the cart
```

The quantity limitation of cart items doesn't seem to be a built in option.